# Linked Service parameterization not working for Linked Service of type Azure Data Explorer (Kusto)

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-explorer

I initially successfully created the following linked service in ADFv2 of type AzureDataExplorer for accessing my database in ADX called CustomerDB:-

```
{
"name": "ls_AzureDataExplorer",
"properties": {
    "type": "AzureDataExplorer",
    "annotations": [],
    "typeProperties": {
        "endpoint": "https://mycluster.xxxxmaskingregionxxxx.kusto.windows.net",
        "tenant": "xxxxmaskingtenantidxxxx",
        "servicePrincipalId": "xxxxmaskingspxxxx",
        "servicePrincipalKey": {
            "type": "AzureKeyVaultSecret",
            "store": {
                "referenceName": "ls_AzureKeyVault_MyKeyVault",
                "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
            },
            "secretName": "MySecret"
        },
        "database": "CustomerDB"
    }
},
"type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices"
```

}

This worked smoothly. Some values I had to mask for obvious reasons but just wanted to say that there is no issue with this connection. Now inspired from this Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/parameterize-linked-services) I am trying to create a generic version of this linked service, which makes sense because otherwise if I have 10 databases in the cluster, I will have to create 10 different linked services.

So I tried to create the parameterized version in the following manner:-

```
{
"name": "ls_AzureDataExplorer_Generic",
"properties": {
    "type": "AzureDataExplorer",
    "annotations": [],
    "typeProperties": {
        "endpoint": "https://mycluster.xxxxmaskingregionxxxx.kusto.windows.net",
        "tenant": "xxxxmaskingtenantidxxxx",
        "servicePrincipalId": "xxxxmaskingspxxxx",
        "servicePrincipalKey": {
            "type": "AzureKeyVaultSecret",
            "store": {
                "referenceName": "ls_AzureKeyVault_MyKeyVault",
                "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
            },
            "secretName": "MySecret"
        },
        "database": "@{linkedService().DBName}"
    }
},
"type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices"
```

}

But while publishing the changes I keep getting the following error:-

[image]

Is there any solution to this?

The article clearly says that:-

> For all other data stores, you can parameterize the linked service by selecting the Code icon on the Connections tab and using the JSON editor

So as per that my changes should have been published successfully. But I keep getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

It appears I need to specify the parameter elsewhere in the same JSON. The followed worked:-

```
{ 
"name": "ls_AzureDataExplorer_Generic",
"properties": {
    "parameters": {
                "DBName": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
    "type": "AzureDataExplorer",
    "annotations": [],
    "typeProperties": {
        "endpoint": "https://mycluster.xxxxmaskingregionxxxx.kusto.windows.net",
        "tenant": "xxxxmaskingtenantidxxxx",
        "servicePrincipalId": "xxxxmaskingspxxxx",
        "servicePrincipalKey": {
            "type": "AzureKeyVaultSecret",
            "store": {
                "referenceName": "ls_AzureKeyVault_MyKeyVault",
                "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
            },
            "secretName": "MySecret"
        },
        "database": "@{linkedService().DBName}"
    }
},
"type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices"
}
```